Why does the Wurtz-Fittig reaction occur?
In the Wurtz-Fittig reaction, an aryl halide and an alkyl halide react with sodium in the presence of dry ether to give R-Ar as the major product. Why is the coupling of R and Ar favoured? In other words, why isn't R-R or Ar-Ar formed as the major product?
(R denotes alkyl group while Ar represents the aryl group)

It is a question of randomization. Let's imagine that mixture of a moles of ArX and b moles of RX reacts with $\ce{Na}$. If the aryl halide Ar-X and alkyl halide R-X are reacting with about the same speed, the reaction produces first a mixture of a aryl Ar and b alkyl R radicals. When recombining, these radicals produce 2ab ArR molecules and also $\ce{a^2}$ Ar2  and $\ce{b^2}$ R2  molecules. Of course 2 ab is bigger than $\ce{a^2}$ or than $\ce{b^2}$.

The reaction follow either or both of following mechanism:

Organo-Alkali Mechanism: When the aryl halide is reacted with sodium metal, an intermediate organo-alkali compound is formed, which is followed by a nucleophilic attack of the alkyl halide as shown below. Thus, the required alkyl-aryl is formed.



Radical Mechanism: The sodium atom acts as a moderator for the formation of alkyl radicals and aryl radicals. These alkyl and aryl radicals now combine to form a substituted aromatic compound


(Reaction mechanism and Image source)
Both of the mechanism end with coupling of alkyl and aryl part, so we get a mixed product.
More info:

Does Wurtz-Fittig-reaction involves Sn1 or Sn2?
Why we need halogens of different periods in wurtz-fittig reaction? + which is the correct mechanism?


The recombination of alkyl and aryl radicals give not one but three three products : 1)alkyl-alkyl, 2) aryl-aryl. and 3) alkyl-aryl
